# Dual-Boot Ubuntu 18.04/Windows 10 No Room

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, multi-boot, disk-management

I am trying to dual boot my Dell Latitude D7270 with Windows and Ubuntu Desktop 18.04. When I enter I look at my storage in settings it says my C: drive has 98GB free (230 GB Total). Yet when I try to partition off the drive in Disk Management (right click on C:, click shrink volume) it only gives me the option to partition ~100MB (see attached image). What's wrong, why can't I partition off a reasonable amount of space?

Comment: There's no image

Comment: Try running a defrag on C: first.